# Issue with add method in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have 2 classes BSTSet and BSTNode. Each class has an add method. My problem is that I think my add method is just adding a node to the left or to the right in a linear fashion, am I correct in saying that? If so how do I get around the issue.

```
public class BSTSet <E extends Comparable<E>> extends AbstractSet <E> {

// the root of the supporting binary search tree
private BSTNode<E> root;

// number of elements in the set
private int count = 0;


public boolean isEmpty() {
    return count == 0;
}


public boolean contains(E item) throws ClassCastException {
    if(root == null) return false;
    return root.contains(item);
}

public boolean add(E item) {
     if (item == null) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null cannot be added to a BSTSet");
     if(contains(item))return false;
     if(root == null){
        root = new BSTNode(item);
        count++;
        return true;
     }else{
        root.add(item);
        count++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class BSTNode <E extends Comparable<E>> {

private E value;
private BSTNode<E> left;
public BSTNode<E> right;

public BSTNode(E value) {
this.value = value;
}

public E getValue() {
    return value;
}

public BSTNode<E> getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public BSTNode<E> getRight() {
    return right;
}


public boolean contains(E item) {
   int comp = item.compareTo(value);
    if(comp  == 0) return true;
    if(comp < 0 && left != null && left.contains(item)) return true;
    if(comp > 0 && right != null && right.contains(item)) return true;
    // no matching node was found
    return false;

}

 public boolean add(E item) {
     if(item.compareTo(value) < 0) {
        if (left == null){ left = new BSTNode(item); return true;}
        else return left.add(item);
    }
    if(item.compareTo(value) > 0) {
        if (right == null){ right = new BSTNode(item); return true;}
        else return right.add(item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: No, you are not correct. Your method `BSTNode.add` always compares the item with the current node's value (in each recursion step) and then decides to either go left or right. So, why do you think that your `add` method does not work correctly?

Comment: I am running tests on the add method. I have the numbers 1 5 2 4 6 8 7 11 25. Everytime it adds a node I get it to print the value to see if its gone left or right. I have noticed that 11 and 25 both say left when they should say right. So thats why I believe something is wrong. I am using an online BST visualizer to see where everything should be.

Comment: And what did prevent you from posting that important information inside the question?

Comment: Well I assumed that it was going in a linear fashion, sorry still learning :/